# AngularJS: Bundle all partial views/templates for production

Tags: html, angularjs, view, production-environment

I wish to keep views as modular as possible. In practice it means I have lots of small generalized HTML snippets, from which the actual HTML page is composed. Now `ng-include` and custom directives with `templateUrl` suit me quite well, but only **in development**, because each HTML snippet is being requested separately.

**In production**, however, I expect a single page app to be, ummm, in a single page, all bundled and minified — just like the JavaScript module loaders (RequireJS, Component, Browserify, DuoJS, etc.) would do to modular JavaScript files. No extra HTTP traffic for loading HTML chunks is acceptable.

Now I'm pretty sure AngularJS does not do bundling out-of-the-box (I would've found it by now), but maybe you guys have come up with something to address this issue?

P.S. It should be noted that I am not looking for cache-related solutions.

Comment: Have a look at the `$templateCache`. With grunt you can merge all your templates into the JS files. This way when your application is loaded, it doesn't have to refetch your templates via http

Comment: FWIW, I ended up using Browserify with [brfs](https://github.com/substack/brfs), because this kind of workflow is _way_ more convenient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use [grunt-angularjs-template](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates)

it does concatenates all templates in one file. as per its docs

> Grunt build task to concatenate & register your AngularJS templates in
>   the $templateCache

if you are using gulp, the gulp equivalent of it is [gulp-angular-templatecache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache)

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using **gulp** then a good option would be [gulp-angular-embed-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-embed-templates)

Comment: agreed this is better thing to do